# Meaning of (と)感じました

Tags: particle-と

I know that と can be used to mark your own thoughts, so in the following phrase:

> すぐに何かおかしいと感じました - I sensed immediately that something was wrong.

Is it right to say that the usage of と in this case is to say that "I'm the one who is thinking (feeling) that something is wrong" or is it a different use of と? If so, can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This と marks the content of actions such as 思う, 書く and 感じる.

> > すぐに何かおかしい**と**感じました。
>
> I immediately sensed **that** something was wrong.

The predicate of the clause marked by this と can be in the dictionary form, ta-form, nai-form or plain command form. In this case, it's in the dictionary form, おかしい.